# Out of memory on all Solr slaves of the same shard

Tags: java, tomcat, solr

We are using Apache Solr 3.5 to drive our website catalog search. We use Field collapsing feature with multiple shards, each shard supporting a cluster of read only slaves.

Recently, we ran into Out of Memory errors on all slaves of a particular shard. We use field collapsing on a particular field which has only one specific value on all the documents of the shard, whose slaves went out of memory. Interestingly, the Out of Memory error recurred multiple times during the day (about 4 times in 24 hours) without any significant deviation in traffic from the normal. The max heap size allocated to the each slave is 8 Gb on a 16 Gb Machine.

Since then we have done the following and the problem seems to be arrested for now -

1. Added more horizontal slaves to the problem causing slave group, from 3 we have brought this up to 6.
2. We have increased the replication poll interval from 5 minutes to 20 minutes. We found out that the background process SolrSearchIndexer.warm is consuming the maximum amount of heap space(about 6 Gb), precisely when the queries start going out of memory. Since a replication interval causes the warming of searchers we thought of increasing the frequency.
3. We have decreased the minimum heap allocation to tomcat on all slaves of this group to 1Gb. Earlier this was 4Gb.
4. One of 3 problem slaves was having write.lock exceptions on an unused core. We have since then removed the unused core on all slaves since it was replicating from another master Solr. The unused core had about 1.5 million docs that consumes about 605 Mb on the disk.
5. We dropped the entire index on all the slaves and replicated everything from scratch. Incidentally one of the slaves had an unusually big size of index on the disk - 2.2 Gb as compared to 1 Gb on other slaves.

The typical size of index directory on the problem shard is around 1Gb, about 1 million documents in all. The average requests served are about 10/second for each slave.

We have tried replaying the entire logs for the day on a test environment but somehow the test solr never goes out of memory with the same heap settings. Frankly, we are not certain that this would not happen again.

Can someone suggest what could be the problem here ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quiet sometime since this happened but I think it will be worthwhile to share the reason here. Our website was being scraped by someone who was using very big start param in the queries. The Solr  distributed index has a limitation on the size of the start parameter(in excess on 500000). The out of memory used to occur when a  heavy replication happened and the coordinating shard already had a lot of documents in memory coming in from the contributing nodes because of a high start parameter.

Details can be found here - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch#Distributed_Searching_Limitations

Our solution was to put a cap on the start parameter to about 1000 as humans rarely go beyond the first few pages of listing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it comes to the caches definition. How many searchers have you allowed to reside in parallel (defaults to 2 but you can change)? Searcher warmup is actually a cache warmup, so if you have a working searcher and a warming searcher, it occupies twice a memory size. What caches do you utilize (document/query/filter/field/custom)? Are you using facets extensively (they use field cache internally)? Many different filter queries (FQ) (again, cached bitmap)?
I think that field collapsing also uses field cache.

Comment: We have not changed the default number of Searchers. This is the cache configuration that we use - 

<filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="4096" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="1365" />
<queryResultCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="2500" initialSize="200" autowarmCount="80" />
<documentCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="65536" initialSize="4096" autowarmCount="10922" />
<queryResultWindowSize>60</queryResultWindowSize>

Comment: How many fields do you have? How many field facets defined?Each field facet means field cache. What is the average document size? 1K?100K?1Mb? BTW, 4096 filters means about 500Mb for 1mln documents. 65536 cached documents can be pretty large.